# float random.uniform to 4 decimal places in python

Tags: python, random

I am having problem rounding floating value to a decimal number greater than 1.

```
def float_generator(size=6, chars = 6):
    return random.uniform(size,chars)
```

and i tried

```
target.write(str(float_generator(7,3)))
```

the above returns random float to 1 decimal num like 1.2222 , 1.333333
I want to generate 7 decimal and 3 points as illustrated in the 7,3

i tried  rounding off below. It round up the points instead .

```
 target.write(str(format(float_generator(7,3),'.3f')))
```

Please how do i achieve 12345432.123 instead of 1.222343223 ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `size=6, chars = 6` don't really make sense, uniform returns *random floating point number N such that a <= N <= b for a <= b and b <= N <= a for b < a.* where is is size and b is chars in your function

Comment: Describe what sort of numbers you want to get

Comment: @JohnColeman the numbers i am after is floating number. It satisfied my requirement. I am just not satisfied with the 1 decimal place and i understand uniform returns loating point number N such that a <= N <= b for a <= b and b <= N <= a for b < a as explained by the user above. I am asking if there is a tweak where i cn get more than one decimal numb instead. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `decimal` and `random` to return a `Decimal` object if you want fine-tuned control of decimal places:

```
import random, decimal

digits = list('0123456789')
def float_generator(size = 6, chars = 6):
    base_str = ''.join(random.choice(digits) for i in range(size))
    dec_str =  ''.join(random.choice(digits) for i in range(chars))
    return decimal.Decimal(base_str + '.' + dec_str)

>>> float_generator(7,3)
Decimal('4768087.977')
```

`Decimal` objects can be fed to float:

```
>>> float(decimal.Decimal('4768087.977'))
4768087.977
```

If you always want a float, you can replace the last line of the function by:

```
return float(decimal.Decimal(base_str + '.' + dec_str))
```

Comment: Its indeed a smart alt . Never thought of doing that. thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is a solution for you:

```
import random
def float_generator(size = 6, chars = 6):
    return round(random.uniform(10**(size-1),10**(size)), chars)
```

call it:

```
float_generator(7,3)
```

output example:

```
2296871.988
```

or better:

```
float_generator = lambda size, chars: round(random.uniform(10**(size-1),10**(size)), chars)
```

call it the same way.